# How to re order the order of a data frame to match the order of 2nd data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have two data frames for an example:

df1:

```
  x    y
0 1.1. 2.1
1 3.1  5.1
```

df2:

```
x    y
0 0.0  2.2
1 1.1  2.1
2 3.0. 6.6
3 3.1  5.1
4 0.2  8.8
```

and I want df2 to match the order that matching values that are in common but keeping the values that don't match after the order, how would I do that using pandas? or maybe something else.

desired output:

new_df:

```
    x    y
0  1.1  2.1
1  3.1. 5.1
2  0.0  2.2
3  3.0  6.6
4  0.2  8.8
```

rows 2-4 I don't care about the order as long as the matching rows follow the same order as df1. I want the values of indexes of df1 and df2 to be equal

any way to do this?

sorry if the way I submitted this is wrong.

thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using `merge` with `indicator` sort as default

```
df1.merge(df2,indicator=True,how='right')
Out[354]: 
     x    y      _merge
0  1.1  2.1        both
1  3.1  5.1        both
2  0.0  2.2  right_only
3  3.0  6.6  right_only
4  0.2  8.8  right_only
```

Comment: the only problem with this is that it adds an additional row to the end for some reason not sure why. any suggestions?

Comment: @BVOM you need check the duplicate whether you df2 and df1 in your side have duplicate row

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat` with `drop_duplicates`:

```
 pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     x    y
0  1.1  2.1
1  3.1  5.1
2  0.0  2.2
3  3.0  6.6
4  0.2  8.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the .combine_first & .update methods.

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
```

They are explained in the [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns).

Comment: This re-create the row by index ...he need the value match, check your output , you have duplicate row for 3.1, 5.1